# Putting the images in firebase under the particular id

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to upload a image in firebase.If selected particular id store the images in particular folder in firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
 StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("profilImages")
            .child(uid + ".jpeg");
```

It stock the image under profilImages as a uid.jpeg
May it was a part of the answer.